# Windows 7 & 10 how to make them friends

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, clonezilla, boot-partition, hiren

I need to clone my current installation of Windows 7 to a new computer. I also need to dual boot that with a new installation of Windows 10. The Windows 7 is currently on a BIOS/mbr disk. I don't mind keeping BIOS/mbr partition table, and using the last 4th slot for Windows 10, but the problem is after using CloneZilla to copy the Windows 7 partitions to the new PC, and then installing Windows 10, it gives me a message saying if Windows 10 is on hardware that has an EFI anywhere on it, even if I am currently in BIOS/legacy Mode, then it must use EFI/GPT installation.

Is there a way to force it to install anyway? 0r could I install Windows 10 on an older PC with BIOS/MBR, and then clone that to the new one? What is the best solution here? I have tried using UEFI/GPT mode with Win 10 instllation, and then cloning the windows 7 partition to the disk, and it does get to the Win7 startup screen, but it never gets to the Win7 login screen.

The reason I must clone an existing Win7 partition instead of installing a new one is there is an application inside that I cannot reinstall, I have already contacted the corporation who made it, so I must preserve it. And yes, I know I can virtualize this disk, I am looking to try to do this without virtualizing it.

I have tried LazeSoft, but it did not fix it (normally a good utility!).

Ideas?? I just need the Windows 7 partition to boot fully to the login screen . . .

0 , 0  ?

Comment: You could run w7 as a VM in W10.  It has several advantages - you don't need to reboot one to use the other.  You can run both concurrently.  You can save the state when you shut down the VM.  The next time you use it, it will restore the state to the point at which you left off.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Windows 10 installation media boots in EFI mode by default and demands GPT partition table for your disk.
You should force the installation media to boot in MBR mode.

1. Call the boot menu when you computer starts (the [list of boot menu keys](https://www.disk-image.com/faq-bootmenu.htm) for the brands);
2. Make sure that you select non-EFI (MBR / Legacy) option for you Windows 10 installation media.

You might need to disable EFI-boot in your UEFI/BIOS.

P.S. You can always **bypass the windows PE problems** (e.g. Win 11 incompatible PC) **by manually extracting OS** to a new partition with tools like imagex (gimagex) or dism:

**A.** Easy one (using your current old Windows):

1. Boot to your into current Win OS;
2. Create a new NTFS partition and mount it;
3. List the available Windows images in install.wim (install.esd) using [GImageX](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Plugins/GImageX.shtml) (the easiest but doesn't support ESD) or using DISM;
4. GImageX Apply or DISM Apply the desired image to the created new partition;
5. Use [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (there's a free version) to add the new boot record

**B.** Directly from Win PE (Windows installation media).
**Don't run the bcdboot** if you want to add the second OS. For dualboot use rebuildbcd instead. Here is the [manual](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/84331-apply-windows-image-using-dism-instead-clean-install.html) with screenhots. TL;DR:

1. Press Shift+F10 directly from Win 10 PE to call the cmd;
2. Create a new NTFS partition and mount it (use `diskpart` and `format`);
3. = Step A.3. (you can pre-copy GImageX to USB);
4. = Step A.4.;
5. run `bootrec /rebuildbcd` to add the new OS to the boot menu.

Comment: I know how to change between BIOS/UEFI modes. Unfortunately, Windows 10 can detect if the motherboard CAN support a UEFI, even when it is in legacy/BIOS mode at that moment. It displayed a message saying all that. Even if I am in legacy/BIOS mode, Windows 10 installation refuses to use an MBR Partition Table.

Comment: Today I have migrated my Windows 7 image into Windows 10 Virtual Box. My Windows XP Mode/Virtual PC is nested inside of that. Unfortunately there is a difficult error I have spent hours working on now. When I open Windows Virtual PC/XP Mode, it says "Windows XP Mode could not be restored because of either host-processor type mismatch or lack of hardware-assisted virtualization support in the system.

Comment: I have tried the following to troubleshoot the above error:
Fully updated the physical Windows 10 64 bit
Fully updated the now virtual Windows 7 64 bit
Installed Virtualbox Guest additions
Installed Virtubox Extension
The Virtualbox System settings had VT-x virtualization support greyed out, and unable to click it, so I performed a Windows 10 Host command line trick and forced it to click.
Confirmed Virtualization is on in the Host system UEFI.

Coincidentally there is also just 1 Windows 7 guest system error, a very large white window says "Your CPU is for newer windows, unsupported.

Comment: Make sure you've enabled virtualization in your UEFI/BIOS. Still nested virtualization is a bad idea on a home PC with home platforms like VirtualBox and VirtualPC. You can export the VirtualPC XP Mode image and run it directly in the VirtualBox environment. Note that VMWare has a better solution called Unity Mode and check if there's a free version of VMware Workstation Player.